# Is it possible to declare an enum which is part of a class in a separate place?

Tags: c++, c++11, declaration, code-readability, enum-class

I have a class with an attribute `type` of a custom enum class `Class::Type`. Currently the declaration of `Class` looks like this:

```
class Class {
    enum class Type {
        a,
        b,
        c,
        ...
    } type;
};
```

But I want to put the declaration of `Class::Type` somewhere else (preferably right *after* the class declaration) so that it doesn't obstruct the visual in the class declaration:

```
//something like this, if it was possible
class Class {
    enum class Type;
    Type type;
};

enum class Class::Type {
    a,
    b,
    c,
    ...
};
```

Is that possible? How?

Comment: This sample compiles fine

Comment: [Compiles for me?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ae6d231dbfa3d1d)

Comment: Weird. I was getting all kinds of error. Looks like I forgot to write `class` in the declaration of `enum class Class::Type`. Thanks for making me notice.

Comment: @user6245072 Did you enable `-std=c++11` at your compiler flags? What's your toolchain, which version?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes I did